# Bootstrap navbar: problem with hamburger after adjusting the navbar height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My navbar is working perfectly fine, hamburger expanding down the menu fine. But after adjusting my navbar height, the hamburger doesn't work perfectly. The hamburger button is working,it still expanding down, but it only show the first menu the rest was cut away like it stucked after halfway showing the first menu(Home) and would not further expand the menu.
After some tweaking, the hamburger will only work 100% with default height.
Any solutions to that?

```
<nav id="navbarMain" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <i class="fas fa-book text-light"></i> Greybook</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Toys</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Store</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
#navbarMain {
    background-color: #525252;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adjusting the navbar height ? Any specific reason

Comment: To make the navbar bigger in size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting a fixed `height`. You could use `min-height: 75px;` instead to make your navbar working again (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4c7z9qa/49/)). However, this solution does not take care about keeping this height.

I would recommend you to increase the height of the navbar by adjusting it's padding (initially defined as `padding: .5rem 1rem;`), like this:

```
padding: 1rem;
```

while will result in a navbar with height `72px`.

[image: Showing height of the solution]

[image: Showing that the solution works properly]

You can find the [running fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4c7z9qa/54/).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you this answer works. Got what I like with 0.6rem :)